Swift forgets @State variable
I set a variable swingPreviewLocation in .inAppear() but Swift forget's it along the way. Printing the variable in the Map view returns nil.
However: Adding a Text() into the body, then Swift remembers and prints
▿ Optional<Location>
  ▿ some : Location
    - latitude : 48.026164457627125
    - longitude : 11.958078424370319

Code:
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct SwingDetailView: View {
    
    var swing: Swing
    
    @State var swingPreviewLocation: Location? // Location is a struct
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            // This helps keep the variable. If I remove it, swift forgets the variable later.
            if let latitude = swingPreviewLocation?.latitude,
               let longitude = swingPreviewLocation?.longitude {
                Text("Latitude: \(Int(latitude)), Longitude: \(Int(longitude))")
            }
            MapReader { reader in
                Map () {
                    let _ = print(self.swingPreviewLocation)
                    if let location = self.swingPreviewLocation {
                        Annotation("Club", coordinate: CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude).coordinate) {
                            Text("C")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear() {
                self.swingPreviewLocation = swing.location
            }
        }
    }
}

class Swing {
    let location: Location?
    init(location: Location?) {
        self.location = location
    }
}


struct Location {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
}


All works well for me in my tests, the Map displays the Location
as desired. Note that the body of the view can be rerendered many times,
and so the first time swingPreviewLocation could be nil, but subsequent refreshes
will have the designated value. Note you don't have to use self. anymore.
Tested with class Swing and struct Swing. Note, edit your question when you want to add more info, don't delete it then post the same question again.

See this link for more info on View and updates,
Custom View
"If an input value changes, SwiftUI notices the change and redraws only the affected parts of your interface. This might involve reinitializing your entire view, but SwiftUI manages that for you". Note, you should also declare @State private var ...
If you use swing.location directly and remove the @State var swingPreviewLocation:..., then the view
will not update again, and there will be no nil value.

Thanks, @workingdogsupportUkraine. The issue is with a MapReader - which I let out of the code to make it simpler.
Somehow you need to reference a variable before using it inside the MapReader.
if let location = swingPreviewLocation {                   
    MapReader { reader in
        Map() {


if you want a new body when a state is set you need to read the state somewhere in body and it must be in a non escaping closure so the read occurs when body is called

@malhal That explains why the MapReader is causing the issue. Can you share a link where I can read up on that?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state "SwiftUI updates the parts of the view hierarchy that depend on the value." It was in some wwdc video where they explicitly said calling the getter is what makes that dependency but don't have the video handy sorry.

The issue is with the MapReader()
Somehow Swift loses the value of the @State variable inside the MapReader closure.
Simple workaround:
if let location = swingPreviewLocation { 
    MapReader { reader in
        Map (interactionModes: [.pan, .zoom]) {
...

